# Excel VBA deleting all duplicate rows that do not contain the highest number

Tags: excel, vba

total VBA noob here trying to sort out how to approach organizing some data. This is auto pulled from a large list and needs condensed down into usable information. But, before it can be condensed down it needs to be cleaned up a tad. The issue I am having is for removing all but the highest number (column H) but only if it is matching with its partners IE column C and D. the data I have looks similar to the posted picture.

[image]

So, in example of the photo - I need to remove rows 5, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 20, 32 and 34
using the above row 5 breaking it down...
row 5 would need removed because there are duplicates in b5 and c5 and h5<h6

this would then shift up the subsequent rows to fill the void of the previously deleted row 5

I feel this is likely a simple VBA script but, once again, I'm a noob and this project is above my head. I have been stuck on this for quite some time and any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Honestly completely stuck on this so any steps in the right direction would be a huge help.

Comment: Sort by C, D and H (descending) then use "remove duplicates" on columns C+D.